# How to prevent systemd.timer immediately restart a service?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, systemd

I have a daemon service that needs to keep working 08:00~16:00 every workday, and I want it exit at 16:00, and keep exited at rest time range and weekend.

I make a systemd.timer for it as following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer of My Service

[Timer]
OnBootSec=25s
OnCalendar=Mon-Fri *-*-* 08:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

It can start up my service at 08:00 every workday, but when the service programm normally exited, the timer starts the service again even through at anytime. This behavior is **NOT** my expecting.
I'm expecting the service only be started exactly at 08:00 and keep exited until next day 08:00, and if the service normally exit, keep exited state whenever.

Escpecially, after I manually stop the service with `systemctl stop myservice.service` command, the timer still restart the service immediately. That results me have to stop the service again.

This is myservice.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service
Requires=postgresql.service
After=postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ms -C /etc/xxx/myservice.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

User=myname
Group=mygroup

OOMScoreAdjust=-1000
TimeoutSec=0
LimitNICE=-10
Nice=-10

[Install]
```

How to do that? thanks!